# How do get rid of the colab error on falcon40b model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run falcon 40B on google jupyter notebook and i get the following error
ValueError: Could not load model tiiuae/falcon-40b with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_auto.AutoModelForCausalLM'>, <class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForCausalLM'>).

I want to run it and see the output